# Need help error handling with angular firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a chat service app and I and getting an error that I cannot figure out the solution for. my code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {User} from '@firebase/auth-types';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
 user!: Observable<firebase.User>;
  userEmail!: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.authService.authUser();
    this.user.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userEmail = user.email;
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Namespace '"C:/Users/steve/met-chat/node_modules/firebase/index"' has no exported member 'User'.ts(2694)

I have made sure that I have updated both angular and firebase to the newest version. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Should `user!: Observable<firebase.User>;` be `user!: Observable<User>;`?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the `import {User} from '@firebase/auth-types';
` line

Comment: @R.Richards It caused an error with a different part of the code for me to now figure out but it fixed the first problem so thank you, it was driving me nuts :)